# Why do I get a blank screen when booting from a CD or USB stick?

Tags: boot, live-cd, live-usb

I'm trying to boot the install from either a usb or cd with the iso file on them, as per umbutu install page. I set my bios to first boot from them ahead of hard drive. When I try the usb it just goes to a black screen with a small cursor blinking in the corner. When I try the cd I get the same thing and then it boots windows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've said "with the iso file on them." Just to be clear, did you actually use the .iso file to make a bootable CD or USB stick, or did you just copy the .iso to your CD or USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've copied the ISO image to the USB stick and CD.

You need to create a bootable CD/USB stick rather than simply copy the ISO image.

There are instructions on the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) web site explaining how to create bootable media.

Scroll down to `2 Burn your CD or create a USB drive` and click on `Show me how`.